# mongodb group with cond, sort and limit

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

i am trying to aggregate a fields based on profit, but i have field with different currencies. I can't figure out how to create a $cond expression that will evaluate more than one expression.

```
db.getCollection("ps_days").aggregate([
    {"$group" : {_id:"$userName", handsCount:{$sum: "$hands"}, profit: {$sum: "$profit"}}},
    {$sort:{"profit":-1}},
    {$limit: 50}
])
```

This query displays group profit. But I need to check the currency in the currency column, then multiply profit it by 1.1 if it is a euro and multiply by 1.4 if it is a pound. Values in the currency column: $, €, £ .
My last query:

```
db.getCollection("888_days").aggregate(
[
    {
        $match: {
           currency: '€'
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            '_id': "$userName", 
            'handsCount': {$sum: "$hands"}, 
            'profit': {
              $sum: {
                $cond: [
                    {$eq: ['$currency', "\$"]},
                    '$profit',
                    {$cond: [
                          {$eq: ['$currency', '€']},
                          {$multiply: ['$profit', 1.1]},
                          {$multiply: ['$profit', 1.4]}
                    ]}
                ]
              }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            'profit': -1
        }
    },
    {
        $limit: 50
    },
]);
```

But it does not work. Is it possible to implement my task in the request?